# jsonp unexpected token : (angular)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, jsonp

When making a http jsonp request, the returned json or xml object always causes the browser to output

- Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.

Or in the case of xml

- Unexpected token '<'. Parse error.

This is my code.

For cross origin purposes, jsonp is needed. Even the [existing examples](http://codepen.io/tutorialab/pen/EJAet) seem to have trouble with certain sites like the one provided here.

Whereas a link such as http://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero, which also requires cross origin request, works flawlessly.

Please tell me what I might be doing wrong and how to resolve this issue, thanks.

```js
app.factory('service', function($q, $http, $templateCache) {
  return {
    getHistoricalData: function(symbol, start, end) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var format = '&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
      var query = 'id=UxxajLWwzqY';
      var url = 'http://ytapi.gitnol.com/get.php?' + query + format;
      $http.jsonp(url)
        .success(function(json) {
          var quotes = json;
          console.log(json); //need to see some results here
          deferred.resolve(quotes);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
app.controller('ContentCtrl', function($scope, service) {
  $scope.getData = function() {

    var promise = service.getHistoricalData($scope.symbol, $scope.startDate, $scope.endDate);

    promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.items = data;
    });
  };
  $scope.getData();
});
```

Comment: `var quotes =JSON.strigify(json);
quotes =JSON.parse(quotes)`